# sql query working in phpmyadmin - not working within php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a function in a `WordPress plugin` I am about to write (my first one) that should check if a given **ID belongs to a user with a certain role** (`'dance_couple' in this case`).

`$sc_user_id` is the id passed in the shortened code.

```
function user_is_dance_couple($sc_user_id){
   global $wpdb;
   $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_value LIKE `%dance_couple%`", $sc_user_id));
   if($count == 1){ return true; } else { return false; }
}

if (user_is_dance_couple(1)) {
  // here comes what should be done if the user has the right role
}
```

**Question**: The weird thing is, that I copied a simpler version of the function (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165691/how-to-check-if-a-user-exists-by-a-given-id) and adapted it. so the only thing I changed is the bit of sql code (that works fine in sql), the function as it was before also works fine - I have no idea what I did wrong.

I already tried:

1. changing the single quotes to the thing between the double quotes " ` "
2. taking the sting out and adding it in a variable
3. adding the table names in before the columns

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `$string` is not doing anything, so it should be removed

Comment: @maya Would you please remove `$string` variable from your query and after check it?

Comment: `%dance_couple%` should be '`%dance_couple%`'

Comment: $string variable is gone - but can't be the problem ... wasn't there before (as explained in list, that just was one of several tries)
@itzmukeshy7 - I tried that - didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for SQL queries. You could do something like that:

```
$user_id = 1; # or whatever user you need
$role_to_find = 'dance_couple';

$user = get_userdata( $user_id );

if( false !== $user ){
    # User found, do your stuff
    $user_roles = $user->roles;
    # var_dump( $user_roles );

    if( in_array( $role_to_find, $user_roles ) ){
        echo 'User has the role';
    }else {
        echo 'User does not have the role';
    }
}else{
    echo 'User not found';
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot - I already had something similar - but without the second variable in "in_array" - maybe the plain text killed it or I made some other mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the GLOBAL object $wpdb inside a query and inside the quotation. What I would do is create another variable and put the value of $wpdb->usermeta in that variable.

in this way:

```
$user = $wpdb->usermeta;
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %d WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_value LIKE `%dance_couple%`";
$count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($query, $user, $sc_user_id));
```

Or the long version:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %d WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_value LIKE `%dance_couple%`", $user, $sc_user_id));
```

The syntax of the query looks correct,
try in this way